# How to make seperate SESSION for different URLs?

Tags: session, session-variables, session-cookies

Hey guys I'm new to PHP.
I have a login page where I m setting some SESSION and logging in to view my pages.
I have one more login page where I m setting different SESSION values and logging in.

Now on loggin to first page I am able to view pages but when I login with page2 in new tab , page1 starts using SESSION values of page2..

How can I seperate these SESSIONS??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All opened tabs of your browser uses the same session. You need to use different names for your session variables

Comment: `@Sean Doe` Can I do so without making changes in the file where SESSION is created?

Comment: You can set session variables everywhere in your code so try to do it in function where you log in user.